# Modify a symlink with shell script

Tags: bash, shell, symlink

I want to modify the target of existing symlink with shell

```
execute "ln -sf $PROJECT_PATH$PROJECT_VERSION $ACTIVE_PROJECT_SYMLINK"
```

But is not working, I have the old target for the symlink. Have you an idea why ?

Comment: You need to delete or rename the old symlink, no way around it

Comment: @Fravadona working with `ln -sfn`

Comment: `ln -fs "$PROJECT_PATH$PROJECT_VERSION" "$ACTIVE_PROJECT_SYMLINK"`